# Небольшая проблема с переменной

Tags: php, переменные

Проблема в том, что **значение переменной test** отображается не с первого раза. По идее так и должно быть. Если в условии `if(!$test)` прописать `if(!$session->get('test'))`, то всё ок, но так не годится.

Как сделать, чтобы мой способ отображал всё с первого раза, а не со второго?

```
$test = $session->get('test');

if(!$test) {
 $session->add('test', 'asdasd');
}

echo $test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну та когда вы переопределили переменную в сессии вы ее не переопределили в скрипте.

```
$test = $session->get('test');

if(!$test) {
 $session->add('test', 'asdasd');
    $test = $session->get('test');
}

echo $test;
```